# How do i read content of this object

Tags: php, web

I'm developing a SMS reading application in PHP. I connected the SMS portal to the application and receive the SMS.

Please help me to read this array object and get content separately.

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (8) 
        { 
            ["message"]=> string(3) "G56" 
            ["messageId"]=> int(1) 
            ["recipients"]=> string(11) "94714369777" 
            ["retries"]=> int(1) 
            ["sender"]=> object(stdClass)#15 (1) 
                { 
                    ["alias"]=> string(11) "94710200542" 
                } 
            ["sequenceNum"]=> int(1) 
            ["status"]=> int(1) 
            ["time"]=> string(25) "2018-10-13T10:40:17+05:30" 
        } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#16 (8) 
        { 
            ["message"]=> string(4) "A67i" 
            ["messageId"]=> int(1) 
            ["recipients"]=> string(11) "94714369777" 
            ["retries"]=> int(1) 
            ["sender"]=> object(stdClass)#17 (1) 
                { 
                    ["alias"]=> string(11) "94710200542" 
                } 
            ["sequenceNum"]=> int(1) 
            ["status"]=> int(1) 
            ["time"]=> string(25) "2018-10-13T10:40:21+05:30" 
        } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#18 (8) 
        { 
            ["message"]=> string(6) "Vhhj99" 
            ["messageId"]=> int(1) 
            ["recipients"]=> string(11) "94714369777" 
            ["retries"]=> int(1) 
            ["sender"]=> object(stdClass)#19 (1) 
                { 
                    ["alias"]=> string(11) "94710200542" 
                } 
            ["sequenceNum"]=> int(1) 
            ["status"]=> int(1) 
            ["time"]=> string(25) "2018-10-13T10:40:24+05:30" 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Isn't it $arrayName[0]->message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a stdObject so you can access it like a simple object:

```
foreach($messages as $sms) {

   $message = $sms->message;
   $messageId = $sms-> messageId;
   $recipients = $sms-> recipients;
   $retries = $sms->retries;
   $sender = $sms->sender['alias'];
   $sequenceNum = $sms->sequenceNum;
   $status = $sms->status;
   $time = $sms->time;

   //...Do your work here
}
```

If you want you can convert it to an array and access the properties like array fields

```
$arr = (array) $sms;
$arr['message'];
```

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for your support. it's really help me. thanks for the quick support

Answer (score 0):

Read object value using -> oprator

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  $message = $value->message;
}
```